# How would you math random & use substring in python(Converting NodeJS to Python)

Tags: python, node.js, math, random

I'm trying to convert my NodeJS to Python
Here's my NodeJS code

```
const DeviceID = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
```

Here's what I put together in Python what am I doing wrong?

```
DeviceID = str(random.randint(36)[2:15]) + str(random.randint(36)[2:15])
```

Answer (score 1):

First, random.randint(a, b) takes 2 arguments.
it returns a random integer N such that `a <= N <= b`.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

You cannot directly access array position like for an integer unless it is a String type

For example, in Python

```
import random
integer_number = str(random.randint(1000,9999)) #Here, it casts the integer to String Type
print(integer_number) #Integer in String Type
#6362
print(integer_number[2:4])# Which reading the string from index 2 to 3
#62
```

Secondly, Unlike randInt, Math.random() in Javascript is a function that returns a floating-point, a pseudo-random number that's greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1, with approximately uniform distribution over that range.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Also, 36 inside `toString(36)` is a radix.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

In Python, you can do this

```
import random
import string

# printing lowercase
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
print ( ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(22)) )
```

https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-generate-a-random-string-in-python